# Downloading JAXA/GPM_L3/GSMaP/v6/reanalysis" hourly product in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, precipitation, aggregate

I want to download "JAXA/GPM_L3/GSMaP/v6/reanalysis" hourly product for a relatively large area approximately 300000 square km and for a long period of time, say 15 years, since this product is hourly, the resulting tiff files will be too many and after 2 hours of waiting for the product to be ready for download from google drive the running process stops for an Internal Error message.

Do I need to aggregate hourly data to at least daily  summation to make it easier to download?

The link to my code for downloading data in stacked form is
https://code.earthengine.google.com/17a92bae24f7445113495668883d03d8. The code is also mentioned in the next lines.

````
var GSMap = ee.ImageCollection("JAXA/GPM_L3/GSMaP/v6/reanalysis")
.filterBounds(geometry)
.filterDate("2001-01-01", "2014-03-01");

// Choosing bands.
var Preci = GSMap.select("hourlyPrecipRateGC");

// Stacking bands.
var Preci_stack = Preci.toBands();

// Converting band names which is a list of dates to feature collection. 
var bandNames = Preci_stack.bandNames();
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(bandNames.map(function(point) {
  return ee.Feature(null, {'value': point});
}));

// Exporting the generated feature collection to csv.
Export.table.toDrive(fc, 'GSMap_Hourly_Precipitation_test');

// Exporting generated images to google drive.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image : Preci_stack,
  description : "GSMap_Hourly_Precipitation_test",
  scale : 10000,
  region : geometry,
  crs : "EPSG:4326",
});```
````

Comment: The output, as specified, will be roughly 4300 pixels x 115,368 dates.  That's roughly 10GB as a CSV, or a 115,386 band geotiff, which is not something I would expect any piece of desktop software to handle well.  Since neither of those sounds particularly useful, in what format could you handle that data?

Comment: @NoelGorelick. Thanks for your attention. what format do you recommend me? apparently GEE only provides data with geotiff and TIFrecord (which I do not know what exactly) format. One solution which popped into my mind is to download each year's data separately but it seems that even one year can't be downloaded properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.